# How to use DynamoDB Stream and lambda functions to sync multiple tables

Tags: lambda, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-streams

I have a very common use case that need sync 2 dynamoDB tables. The logic flow would be the following.

1. A Job is created in Job Table
2. Multiple Requests are created in Request Table. All the requests are created from one Job, like many to one relationship.
3. Requests are processed by some other workers.
4. Each request will marked as done independently in Request Table.
5. When all requests for a certain job is finished, mark a job is done in Job table.

Right now, My thinking is to enable stream on Requests table. When ever a request is finished, it will trigger a lambda function to check if all the requests are finished.

I have read a lot of documents. And find many limitations of this approach:

1. It seems stream+lambda will guarantee that each stream shard will trigger a lambda function at least once, however not only once. Thus the lambda function has to be idempotent. (Let the lambda function to increase the number of finished requests will not work here).

So, I think I have to scan the requests table each time when a lambda function is triggered. Will this approach have to much overhead?

2. DynamoDB stream tends to dispatch every event into different shards. Each shard whenever is filled up will trigger a lambda function. I am not sure what if a shard is half filled for a long time(no events to the table). Will it still trigger the lambda function somehow?

I am also open to all other solutions that could solve this problem. I am not sure if I follow the best practice here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can solve it by using another DynamoDB server.

You can create a separate table in DynamoDB:

**FinishedTasks**
**JobId** - partition key - id of a job
**FinishedRequestId** - sort key - id of a finished request

Every lambda job would do the following:

1. Read new item from a stream
2. Write new item to the **FinishedTasks**
3. Read all finished tasks for a job id
4. Check if all tasks are finished
5. If all tasks are finished, do what is necessary

In this case you have an idempotent task (it does not matter if you override an item in the **FinishedTasks** twice)

Of course you need to remove old items from **FinishedTasks**. To can use the [TTL feature](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/TTL.html) to automatically remove old items.

Comment: Thought about the same thing here. Actually, the operation to complete a request will also be inside a lambda function. I considered reading all finished tasks at there. But since this operation is quite critical here, I am afraid the race condition could result no one is triggering the complete operation for a job. (The last two requests comes in at the same time, may both think they are not the last one.) Thus I consider to have a stream to solve some concurrent issues. Anyway, thank you for your advice. I think I will actually use this approach.

Comment: 1. If you complete a task AND do the check in one lambada function your can fail midway (e.g. power outage on Lambda host) and you will have inconsistent results. 2. "The last two requests comes in at the same time, may both think they are not the last one". You NEED to use strongly consistent reads here to ensure that when a task reads data it reads the latest data, not stale data: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.ReadConsistency.html

Comment: 1.Yeah, I agree that error in the middle could cause trouble. I think I will use step functions here to have retry and error handling support here.

2. Good to know the strongly consistent reads. I will use that. Thank you for the advice.